# find specific child element and change src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to know how i can find a specific element in a div even if there are two of a kind.

```
<div id="man_1">
    <img src="img/img_1.gif" width="80" />
    <img id="img_1" class="test" src="img/img1.png" />
</div>
```

and this jquery:

```
$('#man1').find(".test").attr('src', 'bla.png');
```

my attemp was to find the element trough adding an class and find this. unfortanetly it does not work.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious answer is that you used the wrong `id` in your jQuery, omitting the `_`:

```
$('#man1').find(".test").attr('src', 'bla.png');
```

Should be:

```
$('#man_1').find(".test").attr('src', 'bla.png');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QAbGL/).

If you use the correct `id`, you'll find it works (jQuery doesn't try and *guess* what you're trying to do).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! And we can all use more-kitten in our lives... =)

Answer (score 1):

Fix your id in the selector. from `'#man1'`  to `'#man_1'`

```
 $('#man_1').find(".test").attr('src', 'bla.png');
```

mapping to your element's id:-

```
<div id="man_1">
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aZuWE/)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the child selector

```
$('#man_1 > .text').attr('src', 'bla.png');
```